# To JavaFX [1.3] or not?

Tags: java, javafx, rich-client-platform, javafx-1

We are starting a new Desktop application and considering using javafx but we are a bit confused given the recent announcement by oracle that javafx scripting is not going to be developed further.

Since we cannot wait for javafx 2.0, is it a good idea to use the version 1.3 (which) or should we look at a different technology?

Your opinion will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

JavaFX 2.0 has been released General Availability http://javafx.com
and http://javafx.com/downloads/all.jsp

and the roadmap has been updated http://javafx.com/roadmap/

Comment: I've had a pretty good experience using JavaFX for a fairly complex application, I'd recommend it, it's much better/more modern than Swing. Two small issues though: 1) lack of pixel buffer access 2) bug where there is no depth buffering in JFXPanel (capability class to embed javaFX in existing swing apps).

Answer (score 1):

You should have a close look at the license for JavaFX, particularly the provisions for distribution if you are developing a desktop application.

My understanding of the current 1.3 license is that distribution of the run-time is prohibited, except through Java Web Start.  This is pretty much a deal-breaker for us on the desktop.

Comment: Ooops, well our application is run on a retail point of sale terminal so no internet access or anything...this means javafx is a no no...shame because we were really excited it

Answer (score 1):

There has been an ever increasing trend away from desktop applications to web applications recently, and the advantages are large. Browsers are becoming more sophisticated, so you can do many desktop like features via a browser (and if you are considering JavaFX, then HTML based technologies may give you everything you need).

Also, a web application gives you the flexibility to update your code without having the user update it for you. Most browsers also allow you to launch in application mode (e.g the Chrome -app switch), which locks down the browser to specifically only point at your application.

If you truely want a real desktop experience though, then Swing or SWT should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: we didn't consider them for particular reasons mostly to do with the user interface requirements

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is [Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Rumors of JavaFX script's death have been greatly exaggerated.  It lives on, and is now called [Visage](http://code.google.com/p/visage/).

While development is not incredibly active, over the last 30 days there have been 9 check-ins from 4 different people.

"Wounded"?  Sure.  "Dead"?  Nope.

Comment: I guess the question is "wounded" or "fatally wounded"?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [adobe flex](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/).  This is the technology that appears to be winning this war right now.  I really liked the idea of using JavaFX with existing java work.  I scrapped the idea because it would be really irresponsible to a) use a dead technology that looks like Oracle will not support in the future b) waiting on vaporware is not a good strategy (their JavaFX 2.0 future api).

Someone also mentioned [apache pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/).  Not sure how mainstream that is or what it's future support will be.  According to their [about](http://pivot.apache.org/about.html) it is a mainstream project:

"Pivot joined the Apache Incubator in January 2009 and graduated as a top-level Apache project in December 2009. It is currently driven entirely by the software development community."

I would run, not walk, away from JavaFX 1.3...

JMHO

Answer (score 0):

Java FX2 allows you to leverage existing Java technology. I don't know how you would manage file access etc with html5-javascript. I am using JavaFX2 currently for my project and am happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt that the javafx is improving further and oracle is extending functionality of javafx.
recently oracle announced early release of java 8 in which [javafx](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html) is inbuilt and is having excellent controls.